# Unable to restore a deleted app from App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I had deleted an app for our beta bundle ID from App Store Connect a few months ago. Now I am trying to restore it. But I am getting the following error.
[image]

Can anyone help me in understanding this or let me know how to restore it back?
Because I really don't want to create a new beta bundle ID now.

I don't know if this is helpful, but here's the API response when the restore call is made:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "35b33baf-xxxx",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.INVALID_STATE",
    "title" : "An attribute value is not acceptable for the current resource state.",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "removed"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to contact Apple Developer Support in order to get the issue resolved. They can help you getting the right attribute's value changed.